# maven read property file from jar

Tags: maven

I have a property file in a jar file. How do i read that file using Maven. I have tried using properties-maven-plugin but looks like you have to specify the location of the file. Its a standalone application so I don't see the jar files in the target folder either.

Comment: How is Maven supposed to read the property if you cannot give it full path to the file that contains this property?

Comment: I understand that..that is why I am wonder if there is a different way to go about it. I don't know it, but wondering if someone else has done something like this.

Comment: I think you could achieve this with the maven-dependency-plugin in some way (create a module that, via the dependency plugin, unarchive the jar and copy the resource file into the path where your other module could find it)... but it is worth the trouble...